# Is it possible to style number/bullet lists separately in LibreOffice?

Tags: openoffice, libreoffice

The "Text Body" style in my LibreOffice document uses a large margin above and below each paragraph. This is causing problems in my bulleted and numbered lists since each list item is considered to be a separate paragraph and so there is a lot of unwanted extra space.

I can't see any styles relating to lists, and all text in the list simply has "Text Body" for its style. I could create a new style and apply it to every list in the document, but then I'd have to create a new style and apply it to every list in the document.

Is there a way to style all lists (numbered or bulleted) at once? Is there something in the normal lists of styles or is there another trick?